# Julia language: Inserting global list to a function, change the global list

Tags: julia

I have an information on a global list variables. I want to use this information and make some manipulation with it. But I don’t want to change this global list. Right now any manipulation I make change this global list. I have already a long code code with this global list.

The following example represents my bug difficulty:

```
function Dont_Change_Global_List(L)
Manipulating_List = L
deleteat!(Manipulating_List,2)
return Manipulating_List
end

global s = [1,2,3,4,5]

println("function result: ",Dont_Change_Global_List(s))
println(“global list”, s)

I get:

function result: [1, 3, 4, 5]
global list[1, 3, 4, 5]
```

I need the following result:

```
function result: [1, 3, 4, 5]
global list[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Is there anything I can do without changing the global list s but still make a manipulations?

Answer (score 1):

You can `copy` the list internally:

```
function dont_change_list(L)
    Manipulating_List = copy(L) 
    deleteat!(Manipulating_List,2) 
    return Manipulating_List
end
```